# My billing account google compute engine inexplicably been disabled

Tags: google-compute-engine

Inexplicably without warning my google compute engine billing account was disabled, and I made more intense search and investigation

I followed the steps as described so support page https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3540854?hl=en (Disable or enable billing) in which they explain the following:

```
Enable billingSign in to the Google Developers Console.From the Select a project drop-down list, select a project name.In the upper right, select the Settings icon.From the menu, click Project billing settings.On the Billing page, click the Enable billing button.
```

and the referred button "Enable button billing" to which they refer in step 5 does not appear, I find no way to enable it again.

**Maybe I can be helpful with the following information:**

Yesterday make a payment, there is a probability that is generated authentication problem with my main credit card?

someone has happened to him?

thank you very much for help.

**New information added:**

In effect before writing here I had tried to contact with Billing team support, I wanted to keep trying these days but i do not receive any of any kind answer, I'm a little desperate because I have 6 days with this situation and they have not answered me, I had to open a second ticket as the first left me talking to myself and turned out that second ticket was worse, I have send around 17 messages imploring aid and practically was alone in the desert, and worse not even achievement know the reason for the suspension.

Two executives have assigned to me one for each ticket me and both the executive "Jorge" as the executive "Nadaine" simply left the conversation.

I fear that only seriously cater to customers platinium or gold, as they require them to pay $ 400 monthly, and really seems unfair to have to pay this much just to be heard.

It's sad but true, no one to turn to.

Comment: Please open a ticket with Google Cloud support, instructions here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3420056?hl=en — this is not a technical question that can be addressed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Misha Brukman, It did not help at all the support, left me talking to myself without any reason, please read above for details.

Comment: @RaulObagi I had many problems as well with Google support. I paid the silver account but the service was really really bad. I think if you don't pay you are completely alone. Did you finally solve your problem?